# Media query issues with screens smaller than 768px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Okay.. so here is my code in my head

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Eddy Gann: Designer</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- main -->
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:768px)">
<!-- phone -->
<link href="phone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:768px)">
</head>
```

The main.css displays fine. When I resize a window or look on my iPhone, it does not display any css at all. I have tried putting in "main.css" and it still just stops displaying any css at a screen size bellow 768px.. I don't understand the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set a stylesheet for when the screen size is below 640px

```
only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:768px)
```

This statement means that the media should be electronic, have a width greater than 640px, but less than 768px

Seeing how you have the file named as phone, I would assume that you want this to be for small devices. If that is the case, simply remove `(min-width:640px)`. This will set the styles in that stylesheet to apply whenever the width is below 768px, which includes iPhones

Comment: I don't understand why nothing would display on my iphone with a min width of 640px. That should have at least worked for the iphone, but it didn't.

Comment: Because min-width means minimum width. So the screen size must be bigger than 640px in your delcaration

Answer (score 0):

you can use percantage value For example you have 640x640 resolution screen; if you set `width:100%` your width value is 640px, or if your resolution 1280x1280, then width value is 1280px